# Migration from 1.x to 6.x

Tags: elasticsearch, migration, elasticsearch-5

We want to upgrade the version from 1.x to 6.x as:
I ve setup new cluster with version 6 and I wanna use reindex from remote to transfer data from the old index to new index 
I got this error :

```js
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "parsing_exception",
                "reason": "[reindex] failed to parse field [source]",
                "line": 10,
                "col": 3
            }
        ],
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "[reindex] failed to parse field [source]",
        "line": 10,
        "col": 3,
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "Unsupported fields in [remote]: [index,type]"
        }
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

Comment: May you also post your query and the mappings?

Comment: it's solved i run a false malformated query